# Shifts with beamer

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to use `beamer`.
I use Linux mint with TeX Live 2013.

It seems there are some shiftings in the slides.

The plain example :

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Un titre}
\author{Moi}
\institute{ici}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Un}
\subsection{a}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{truc}
Voici un texte
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

gives me a slide where the upper half is white and when I give more text it is not completely shown.

Everything works fine when I use context.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you mean here: I get two slides, one a 'title page' and one standard slide with the main text vertically centred as expected. We could do with an image of the issue. As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. One of the higher-rep users will then 'fix' it.

Comment: Are you using `pdflatex` or `latex+dvips`? I ask because an incorrect paper size setting for `dvips` could cause the problem you describe. To prevent this you could try `dvips -tlandscape`.